# In Silverlight, how do I display information about the user?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-authentication

I want to display information about the user on a page within a silverlight app. I am using the business template as a starting point, and I am using windows authentication as my authentication method.

If I simply do the following, I get errors about not being logged in yet (the WebContext.Current.User object is not loaded yet):

```
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Title = ApplicationStrings.HomePageTitle;

    txtOutput.Text = WebContext.Current.User.Name + Environment.NewLine;

    foreach (string Role in WebContext.Current.User.Roles)
    {
        this.txtOutput.Text += Role + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

If I do the following, everything loads normaly the first time I load the page, everything is ok, however if I change pages and come back, it does not load because I am already logged in:

```
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Title = ApplicationStrings.HomePageTitle;

    WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoggedIn += new EventHandler<AuthenticationEventArgs>(Authentication_LoggedIn);
}

void Authentication_LoggedIn(object sender, AuthenticationEventArgs e)
{
    txtOutput.Text = WebContext.Current.User.Name + Environment.NewLine;

    foreach (string Role in WebContext.Current.User.Roles)
    {
        this.txtOutput.Text += Role + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

The only way that I have been able to get this to work is using the following code, which to me is a little bit dirty:

```
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Title = ApplicationStrings.HomePageTitle;

        if (WebContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Authentication_LoggedIn(null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoggedIn += new EventHandler<AuthenticationEventArgs>(Authentication_LoggedIn);
        }
    }

    void Authentication_LoggedIn(object sender, AuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {
        txtOutput.Text = WebContext.Current.User.Name + Environment.NewLine;

        foreach (string Role in WebContext.Current.User.Roles)
        {
            this.txtOutput.Text += Role + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

Could someone point me in the right direction of the 'right' way to do this. I like to stick with best practices and this does not seem like it is it.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I found a workaround that might be sufficient. In App.xaml.cs, move the line 'this.InitializeRootVisual();' from the Application_Startup function to the Application_UserLoaded function. This will prevent the application from loading until the user has successfully authenticated. I am sure you could play around with this to make it let the user know that they are being authenticated.